# How to improve the latency of this simple query?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of roughly 112k cities in Firestore, and I want to look up a city based on countryCode using the function below.

If I time this function, without any configured indexes in the Firebase console, it times at roughly 1100ms. If I create an index sorting on name and countryCode, the function takes roughly 950ms.

I am testing from Europe and the server is in the US.

Is this expected behaviour? What would be the best way to improve the latency of this query?

I could set up another database instance in Europe, but I doubt that it will make a huge difference. A simple id lookup takes about 200ms on the same database, so I would expect that at least 800ms of the time has nothing to do with round-trip latency.

```
async function getIdForCity(name: string, countryCode: string) {
  console.time("Get city id");
  const snapshot = await db
    .collection("cities")
    .where("name", "==", name)
    .where("countryCode", "==", countryCode)
    .get();

  if (snapshot.size === 0) {
    throw new Error(
      `Unable to find city with name ${name} and countryCode ${countryCode}`
    );
  }

  if (snapshot.size > 1) {
    throw new Error(
      `There are multiple (${
        snapshot.size
      }) cities with name ${name} and countryCode ${countryCode}`
    );
  }
  const cityId = snapshot.docs[0].id;
  console.timeEnd("Get city id");
  console.log(`City id for ${name}, ${countryCode}: ${cityId}`);
  return cityId;
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that firestore is still in beta. just wondering, since I had similar issue, using `onSnapshot` rather than `get` makes it faster? Also does adding `limit(2)` helps? another workaround is cloud function with cached response

Comment: 800ms for a query seems rather large, although it of course depends on many factors (such as data size, warm up, etc). Can you reproduce this in a place where we can both look at it, such as a jsbin?

Comment: The data / project is not public, so I think I'll have to create a test db and move some data over. Seems like there is no easy export / import for Firestore atm, so I'll have to find some time to do this, but I'll set something up soon.